# Writing an own Language Definition for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

I Am trying to write an own language definition for Promela/Spin and installing it in my Sublime Text.

But I cannot find any way how I can Install the definition.

What format do they need to be in? JSON? PLIST? Where do I need to put them to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html

> Sublime Text uses property list (Plist) files to store syntax definitions. However, because editing XML files is a cumbersome task, we’ll use JSON instead, and convert it to Plist format afterwards. This is where the AAAPackageDev package (mentioned above) comes in.

http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/packages.html

> This is an exhaustive list of Sublime Text resources than can be found inside a package:
>
> ... ... syntax definitions (.tmLanguage) ... ...

Installing a package:

> There are three main ways to install packages:
>
> - .sublime-package archives
> - version control systems
> - copy-pasting of files